# Android Java for loop uses less CPU and is slower than C++ for loop

Tags: java, android, performance, parallel-processing, java-native-interface

I have been exploring efficient ways to do image processing in Android and while comparing a simple point operation like YUV to RGB color space conversion of a 8 mega pixel image (8 million pixels) I got following performance difference between Java & Native simple for-loops while running on a certain Android device (`arm64-v8a` ABI):

| Approach | Average | Verdict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Java | 353 ms | - |
| Native standard | 76.4 ms | 4.62x faster |

By simple for-loops I mean both of them were row major for loops (no tiling, no explicit paralellization, no SIMD instructions)

```java
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        // .. yuv to rgb conversion
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly this is due to the optimisations C++ compiler does for the given CPU architecture. On profiling I observed the C++ code to have good CPU usage while the java code to have much less.

| Approach | Avg CPU usage |
| --- | --- |
| Java | ~12% |
| Native | 70%+ |

This was observed while profiling debug version.

Are there ways to achieve better parallelism (& better throughput) with pure Java code in Android? As in some known APIs or frameworks which allows us to do this easily.

(Please note: the question is strictly about improving performance with Java code and not with alternative frameworks like RenderScript, Vulcan, Halide etc.)

### Update 1 - related to `Mark Keen's` comment

I tried explicitly parallelising the Java code using thread pools & tiling

```java
final int TILES_PER_AXIS = 4;
int tileWidth = width / TILES_PER_AXIS;
int tileHeight = height / TILES_PER_AXIS;
int threadCount = TILES_PER_AXIS * TILES_PER_AXIS;
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
int threadCount = TILES_PER_AXIS * TILES_PER_AXIS;

for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
    int startY = i / TILES_PER_AXIS * tileHeight;
    int endY = startY + tileHeight;
    int startX = i / TILES_PER_AXIS * tileWidth;
    int endX = startX + tileWidth;
    Future<Void> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        process(startX, endX, startY, endY, ...other data);
        return /* Void */ null;
    });
    futures.add(future);
}

// Wait on all futures
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    future.get(); // do anything you need, e.g. isDone(), ...
}
```

And the `process(..)` function only does the task in the given bounds of `(startX, startY)` to `(endX, endY)`

With this I did see both higher CPU usage and performance to a certain limit, but still not satisfied with the CPU usage (& performance with respect to the native code).

##### Pixel 4A, YUV 420 --> Bitmap, 8MP (3264x2448)

| Approach | Threads | CPU usage | Average latency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Direct loops | 1 | ~12% | 353 ms |
| Parallel 2x2 tiles | 4 | ~32% | 173 ms |
| Parallel 4x4 tiles | 16 | ~26% | 129.9 ms |
| Parallel 8x8 tiles | 64 | ~15% | 161.50 ms |

### Update 2 - improved performance with direct `byte[]` access.

One key difference between Java code and native code in this case was the java loops were accessing the data using a readonly [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) while the native code was accessing the underlying data directly. I suppose for loops with direct pointers access are:

1. Less instructions per iteration
2. Easier for the compiler to auto-vectorise.

So one way to address this was using fast `byte[]` copy and doing the conversion using `byte[]`. This of course not so good hit on java heap. Some performance numbers I saw with this:

| Approach | Average | Verdict |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Java (unoptimised} | 353 ms |  |
| Native (unoptimised) | 76.4 ms | 4.62x faster |
| Java `byte[]` + single threaded | 119.5 ms | 2.9x faster |
| Java `byte[]` + multi threaded | 53.8 ms | 6.56x faster |

And CPU usage:

| Approach | Avg CPU usage |
| --- | --- |
| Java `ByteBuffer` + single threaded | ~12% |
| Native | ~70%+ |
| Java `byte[]` + multi threaded | ~33%+ |

My write-up on this topic: [Faster image processing in Android Java using multi threading](https://blog.minhazav.dev/faster-image-processing-in-android-java-using-multi-threading/) (with my limited understanding, but still exploring)

### Questions:

- **Can we do better?**
- Is there a easier way to do this way of tiling in Java?

Comment: Supplied code is single threaded. I assume the native c++ implementation must be mutli-threaded based on the cpu usage i.e a 4 core 4 thread cpu in single thread work load could only max 25% (you might be using a 8-core 8-thread CPU to get 12% in the supplied single threaded code), unless your supplied code is identical in both implementations, which makes the results confusing? Making the Java code mutl-threaded will yield far better results, maybe by "tiling" then processing (think Cinebench) sections/chunks on different threads - forking and joining at the end

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. That is likely the root cause, my question is more directed towards some known APIs / frameworks to achieve better parallelism for this kind of operation (just updated the question).

Comment: This sort of thing is also exactly the use case for vectorized instructions.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- If I understand correctly Java doesn't expose those lower level details via the public APIs? Also, vectorized instructions should help speedup on single core, for this question I am wondering more from higher parallelization perspective to achieve higher CPU usage for better performance.

Comment: I did a bit more research and realised that the LLVM compiler used in Android supports auto vectorisation and given that I am compiling the code with `-O3` flags -  it might be generating SIMD instructions for the simple loops. But, Android started using ART since Android 8.0 and it seems to support Ahead of time compilation with loop optimisations like vectorisation as well. I still don't get both why we get a faster performance with C++ code and cpu usage as high as 70% - is there a concept of running single threaded code over multiple cores or so?

Comment: Note that the way you compute `startX` and `startY` is incorrect: you're processing only the tiles on the diagonal (several times).